# Python os.listdir not working with teller

Tags: python, path, listdir

I'm new with python and have following question (have been searching for hours)
this code is working:

```
    all_files = os.listdir(impath_1)
    im_order = []
```

Now I want to use a teller (in while loop)

```
    newpath = 'impath_'+str(count)
    all_files = os.listdir(newpath)
    im_order = []
```

The error I get is:
system can't find given path 'impath_1/*.*'  (when counter is on 1)

more information: code impath

```
if seq == '1' and turn =='1':
    impath_1 = 'images_block_' + a 
    impath_2 = 'images_block_' + c
    impath_3 = 'images_block_' + e
    impath_4 = 'images_block_' + g
    impath_5 = 'images_block_' + i
```

Comment: By *teller* do you meant *counter*? (teller is Dutch for counter).

Comment: The string `'impath_1'` and the variable `impath_1` are different. It looks like you need a list, not a bunch of numbered variables.

Comment: Don't use numbered variables. Use a list instead. `impath = ['images_block_' + value for value in (a, c, e, g, i)]` would produce a list with 5 values. Then you can loop over that list.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this kind of code:

```
    if seq == '1' and turn =='1':
        impaths = ['images_block_' + a,
                  'images_block_' + c,
                  'images_block_' + e,
                  'images_block_' + g,
                  'images_block_' + i]
```

Here I've created a list, filled with your paths names. Then you should achive them with a counter and maybe a for loop is better, then while loop:

```
    for impath in impaths:
        all_files = os.listdir(impath)
```